# Was org-iswitchb removed, and what is it's closest replacement?

Tags: org-mode, buffers

Just getting started getting comfortable with Org. Part of my initial configuration was copied from [the GNU manual:](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Activation.html)

```
 (global-set-key "\C-cb" 'org-iswitchb)
```

That didn't work ever; for posterity and Googlers, it was giving me this message:

> command-execute: Wrong type argument: commandp, org-iswitchb

<kbd>M-x org-iswitchb</kbd> did show "no match", too. So the function doesn't exist.

Today I discovered that `iswitchb` was removed from GNU Emacs in 24.4 [according to emacswiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IswitchBuffers). So it seems `org-iswitchb` is gone for good, too, and it's not a configuration fault on my end.

What is the current equivalent? Is `org-switchb` it?

(I don't know how iswitchb behaved, so I cannot compare. Alternative suggestions are welcome, too; probably best fitting in the comments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `org-switchb` has been dead for a while.  But it has been resurrected.

> 67a8b4026fe1ce1abbd35d01dd8240189e616a8f Commit:     Nicolas Goaziou
>   CommitDate: Tue Feb 2 22:33:09 2016 +0100
>
> Precedes:   release_9.0 (904)
>
> Resurrect `org-switchb'

Actually I use `org-switchb` occasionally to change to a different org buffer.

I guess the prefix "i" in iswitchb stands for "interactive" and has been dropped in the org implementation because it does not help in any way.

It's still possible to use `M-x iswitchb-mode` to toggle that mode.  `C-x b` with `iswitchb-mode` on feels very much like `org-switchb` AFAICS.

Comment: I'm running Org v9.1.4, actually. The commit message you quote resurrects `org-switchb` -- note the missing "i" of "iswitchb". Can you localize where your `org-iswitchb` is implemented?

Comment: Good catch! You are right, I don't have `org-iswitchb` and I should have read your question more carefully. I update my answer since I think org-switchb is what you are looking for.

Comment: BTW the documentation has been adapted already. You link to a "manual (is) for Org version 8.2.9. " I recommend `M-x org-info` to consult the org info pages.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Didn't notice the Org version in the GNU manual. I wonder why they don't update it.

Comment: It looks org-switchb intends to do exactly what org-iswitchb will do. so far i replace org-iswitchb with org-switchb which works fine. Thanks for the update